# Config HPE servers BIOS Settings By OS

Tags: ubuntu, automation, bios, hpe, hp-server-automation

Is there a way to configure BIOS settings, for example:

1. hyperthreading
   2.date/time
2. power settings
3. BOOT mode
   and etc...
   Can you suggest a package for my needs in Ubuntu?
   I found hpasmcl, but I didn't find a .deb package and I am not sure how to install it on Ubuntu!
   If you could help me, I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do it like that at all, I'd just either write a script to ssh into the iLO and make the changes or write it in Ansible - either way will be more 'transportable' to other systems and be more futureproof.

Comment: I have 400 servers and I want to automate it!do you know any package for it?!

Comment: Yes, Ansible would be ideal

Comment: Can you give me an example by ansible?